# iteration over a C++ map giving infinite loop

Tags: c++, dictionary, infinite-loop

I have the following method in `C++` that only removes the elements associated with a particular `tableId` from a map.

```
 69 void
 70 ObjectFinder::flush(uint64_t tableId) {
 71 
 72     RAMCLOUD_TEST_LOG("flushing object map");
 74     // find everything between tableId, 0
 75     // keep scanning util find all the entries for that table
 76     std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::const_iterator it;
 79     for (it = tableMap.begin(); it != tableMap.end(); it++) {
 80         TabletKey current = it->first;
 81         if (tableId == current.first) {
 82             tableMap.erase(current);
 83         }
 84     }
 85     std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
 87 }
```

Stepping into the code with `gdb` I found out that an infinite loop is happening after the iteration of the `for` loop. The line `85` is never printed out. I'm assuming a dangling pointer is happening. In the first loop, the `current` element is removed, then in the next two nothing happens, and then I have the infinite loop.
I'm total clueless why is this happening. Does someone has an idea or has experienced it before?

Another smarter version of my code is to use `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` to find where the `id` begins (it would save some computing time):

```
 69 void
 70 ObjectFinder::flush(uint64_t tableId) {
 71 
 72     RAMCLOUD_TEST_LOG("flushing object map");
        KeyHash keyHash = Key::getHash(tableId, "", 0);
 74     // find everything between tableId, 0
 75     // keep scanning util find all the entries for that table
 76     std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::const_iterator lower;
        std::map<TabletKey, ProtoBuf::Tablets::Tablet>::const_iterator upper;
        TabletKey key(tableId, keyHash);

        lower = tableMap.lower_bound(key);
        upper = tableMap.upper_bound(key);
        tableMap.erase(lower, upper);
 85     std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
 87 }
```

and I get:

```
/home/ribeiro.phillipe/ramcloud/src/ObjectFinder.cc:81: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, RAMCloud::ProtoBuf::Tablets_Tablet, std::less<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, RAMCloud::ProtoBuf::Tablets_Tablet> > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, RAMCloud::ProtoBuf::Tablets_Tablet> >)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_map.h:566: note: candidates are: void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::erase(typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator) [with _Key = std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, _Tp = RAMCloud::ProtoBuf::Tablets_Tablet, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, RAMCloud::ProtoBuf::Tablets_Tablet> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_map.h:581: note:                 typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::size_type std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::erase(const _Key&) [with _Key = std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, _Tp = RAMCloud::ProtoBuf::Tablets_Tablet, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, RAMCloud::ProtoBuf::Tablets_Tablet> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_map.h:596: note:                 void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::erase(typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator, typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator) [with _Key = std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, _Tp = RAMCloud::ProtoBuf::Tablets_Tablet, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>, RAMCloud::ProtoBuf::Tablets_Tablet> >]
make: *** [obj.master/ObjectFinder.o] Error 1
```

is that because I don't have a `C++` version that support that?

Comment: When erasing an element from a map, the iterator is invalidated. You could `tableMap.erase(current++)` (postincrement is important) with a while loop

Answer (score 10):

Your code has undefined behaviour because you're using an iterator that you've just invalidated. Do it like this:

```
for (it = tableMap.begin(); it != tableMap.end(); )
{
    if (tableId == it->first.first) { tableMap.erase(it++); }
    else                            { ++it; }
}
```

Comment: Kerrek, could I go ahead and ask you another question? It's related to this problem, but instead of looping over the map, I use upper_bound and a key to find where does it begin

Comment: @philippe: Edit your question and I'll try and address it.

Comment: I was having the same issue using the `iterator` from your source code.

Answer (score 2):

```
tableMap.erase(current);
```

This line [invalidates the iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) `it`. Using it afterwards yields undefined behaviour.

You need to advance the iterator before erasing that element. You would need to use something like `tableMap.erase(it++);` and then be careful to skip the regular loop increment.

Comment: R. Martinho, more details about `tableMap.erase(tableId);`?

Comment: I think the key type is a pair...?

Comment: @philippe Oh, forget about that. I misread the code and didn't notice the key was a pair. Thanks Kerrek.

Comment: Yes, the key type is a pair

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I've updated my question too ... please take a look.