# C++ Map iterator stucks in infinite for loop

Tags: c++, dictionary, infinite-loop

I am iterating a `map` in `C++` using a `for loop` but it is stucking in an infinite loop. I have searched for other similar questions and the closest one is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654995/iteration-over-a-c-map-giving-infinite-loop), but answer to that question doesn't answer my query because in that question the author is making changes to the map object but I am not making any changes to the map object during the `for loop`.

My code is follows (I tried commenting different lines and figured out that infinite loop is caused by 11th line (`else statement`) but I couldn't figure out the exact problem ):

```
int main(){
    map<int,int> dic; //dic is the relevant map object
    dic[0]=1; dic[1]=1; dic[2]=1; dic[3]=1; //dic = {0:1, 1:1, 2:1, 3:1}

    int k=1;
    int sol=0;

    for(map<int,int>::iterator iter=dic.begin(); iter!=dic.end(); iter++){
        int a=iter->first; int b=iter->second;
        if(k==0) sol+=b*(b-1)/2;
        else sol+=b*dic[a+k]; //after some trials, I found that problem is in this line but I couldn't figure out the problem
    }
    return sol;
}
```

Comment: [Prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303899/performance-difference-between-iterator-and-iterator) `++iter` to `iter++`.

Comment: Why would that make a difference here?

Comment: It won't affect the correctness of the code, that's why it's just a comment.

Comment: Okay. what's the reason for preferring `++iter` over `iter++`?

Comment: "Prefer" is a reference the question with an explanation.

Comment: I think a little `cout << a << endl;` would have gone a long way towards solving the mystery.

Comment: I used `cout` and it was printing all added values in each loop with pair value of 0 but I didn't know that C++ would automatically add those keys. I was expecting an error in that case (python gives error in that case) :)

Comment: When the behaviour is surprising, [look up](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) what it's supposed to do and compare that to your assumptions. In this case, among the first things you see is "[...] performing an insertion if such key does not already exist."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
sol+=b*dic[a+k];
```

*does* add a new element to the `map` if the key `a+k` doesn't exist.

`a` here *is* a key, so `dic[a]` would work fine. However, when `k` is not `0`, you run the risk of accessing an element of the map that doesn't exist.

Use [`map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) if you want to check whether a particular key exists.

Also, your observation that this code results in an infinite loop, is valid, but technically incorrect. There are only a finite number of values that the key type can have, so *eventually* the loop will terminate. It might take quite a while though. This assumes that you are only ever using keys that don't overflow an `int`.

Comment: `a` is the key, but the same applies: at some point `a+k == 3 + 1 == 4` so `dic[4]` will be created, iteration continues, `dic[5]` will be created, and so on and on.

Comment: @RoelSchroeven That's right, I missed that bit, thanks.

Comment: It should be clarified that the for loop won't result in an infinite loop since `a+k` can take a maximum of `2^32-1` unique values.

Comment: @lucieon Wouldn't it be `2^32`? Eventually the key will overflow, but this code isn't going to stop because of that. It will continue until the computed key wraps around and works its way back up to 0.

Comment: @cdhowie you're right, it's `2^32`. I was thinking of the maximum value it can take while making that comment. But how will it overflow? Whatever be the result of `a+k`, it'll be one of those `2^32` values. And since it's there is a limit to it, `iter` will finally reach `dic.end()`.

Comment: @lucieon Right, not claiming that it will loop forever. However, I believe it's not actually `2^32` iterations either, since `std::map` is ordered. I think the loop will run a maximum of `2^31-1` times (note the exponent is different than in your comment) because once iteration reaches the maximum key, iteration will stop there since we're iterating an ordered set. (While a negative key will get added during that iteration, we won't advance to it.)